# Large data to cloud service

Tags: wcf, azure, ftp, msmq

I need to send about 50 mb of data containing images to a service on Windows Azure.

Should I send it to a WCF service using a binding with MSMQ transpotation, or would it be better to write a worker role service (like a windows service on the cloud) and use FTP to transmit a (possibly compressed) file to the worker role service?

Comment: What about using BLOB storage and upload it as a BLOB?

Comment: If its for data processing you could create an disk and put in storage and mount it for your services. (this is if your data is static and not something you want to upload all the time).

Answer (score 0):

50MB is [quite large](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/08/22/why-is-there-a-4mb-limit-on-msmq-messages.aspx) to be sending as a message.

Transactional queuing over msmq supports large messages by splitting them up into chunks of maximum message size (currently 4MB) and then stitching it back together at destination.

However I'm struggling to understand how you use MSMQ on premise to transmit to an Azure storage queue (or Azure service bus queue).

I think FTP is more suited to moving large files.